# How to mask sections of an image

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm using a layer mask to remove sections of the "sushi" image to leave the tablet and phone images, but I can only do this with the brush tool, right?

I'm wondering how to do this most efficiently because the border between the "sushi" image and the tablet and phone is definitely not a straight line.

What's the best way to do this?

[image]

Comment: You can use any tool on a layer mask. You aren't limited to brushes. Also, if you hold the shift key down with a brush, you paint a straight line.

Comment: I'm just wondering why you'd need to mask anything with such image. Based on the texts in it, I'd say it's a mock up template, but if it is one, why is it a flat image? Makes me think that you stole this image from somewhere.

Comment: It's hard to answer, because you don't say whether the devices are each on different layers, or they are a single image overlaid by the sushi image. Clarify that and we can answer.

Comment: Thank you @Scott, I'll try that. Joonas, not stolen - I'm a reseller for a website building platform and they are happy for me to use various assets. Dominic thanks for the suggestion, but seems a bit more time-consuming than doing it with layer masks. Alan, everything is on a single layer. What would you recommend yourself?

Comment: Hm, I'm still having difficulty with the brush method. I can't figure out how to apply a square brush in CS6 to make it easier. @AlanGilbertson did you happen to have a suggestion?

Comment: I do, now that you've clarified things. Somehow I missed your response, so I apologize for the delay in answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Remove your existing layer mask and hide the top layer.
- Use the pen tool to outline the area on the base image that you want to reveal.
- Turn the path into a selection using `Ctl-Enter` (`Cmd-Backspace`). Use "Refine Edge" to tweak it and apply a 1-pixel feather.
- Invert the selection (`Ctl/Cmd-Shift-I`)
- Reveal the top layer and target it.
- Click the layer mask icon at the bottom of the layers panel.

You will now have masked your overlay layer so that the device images are revealed.